# Footable pagination and sorting is not working

Tags: html, css, footable

First i setup jquery, bootstrap libs and then include footable.min.js, footable.paging.js and footable.sorting.min.js files and also setup stylesheets for that.

So, i can't to use sorting as well as pagination on it.
i am not getting any kind of error in console. whereas i able to used data-breakpoints for various devices and it works for me. i don't know how one features is working and another is not. please help me.

### html file

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
        <table class="footable table table-hover" data-page-size="3" data-page-navigation=".pagination">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-toggle="true">Name</th>
                    <th data-breakpoints="xs sm">Birthday</th>
                    <th data-breakpoints="xs">City</th>
                    <th>Donation</th>
                </tr>           
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sade Morgan</td>
                    <td>10/03/1990</td>
                    <td>Ede</td>
                    <td>$4,653</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Knox Sutton</td>
                    <td>06/29/1966</td>
                    <td>Bressoux</td>
                    <td>$4,563</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rooney Preston</td>
                    <td>12/12/2002</td>
                    <td>Patalillo</td>
                    <td>$3,222</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fulton Wilkerson</td>
                    <td>01/24/1986</td>
                    <td>Haren</td>
                    <td>$2,841</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Azalia Long</td>
                    <td>11/21/1988</td>
                    <td>Gressoney-Saint-Jean</td>
                    <td>$4,631</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Erich Burris</td>
                    <td>10/26/1966</td>
                    <td>Pulle</td>
                    <td>$2,519</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Kadeem Sharpe</td>
                    <td>08/24/1976</td>
                    <td>Ekeren</td>
                    <td>$1,440</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rose Wilcox</td>
                    <td>11/05/2003</td>
                    <td>Aparecida de Goiânia</td>
                    <td>$2,188</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hu Gibson</td>
                    <td>02/18/1994</td>
                    <td>Raigarh</td>
                    <td>$4,286</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
                        <ul class="pagination"></ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".footable").footable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you post this somewhere on JSFiddle, so we can check the issue? or just use a debugger in you browser, to understand what goes wrong.

Comment: Sir, i am using latest version of bootstrap, i think it occurs problem. am i right ???

Comment: Tushar, I don't think actually `footable.sorting` is dependent on bootstrap, as it's separate plugin, which is bound to specific layout structure, which is table.

Comment: Sir, i think its depend on jquery version. please check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bxkeeLLo/5/)